# iteration consistency guarantees of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

im writing a piece of code that needs a point-in-time consistent iterator over a ConcurrentHashMap.

the docs have this to say about iterator consistency:

> guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction

but thats a bit sketchy ("may"). are there any specific guarantees beyond that that are maybe sprcific to ConcurrentHashMap?

if not, is there some other concurrent map implementation that does provide better guarantees? (same-thread point-in-time consistency)

Comment: if you stop to consider implementation concerns, you'll realize that point-in-time consistency cannot be had without locking (you must lock while copying the snapshot), and can be had without problem *with* locking. Personally, I wouldn't think twice before committing to a locking scheme here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - im no expert, but i think in theory you can implement snapshots using atomics without resorting to locking. i know these techniques are used by certain concurrent maps to resize "in the background"

Comment: An immutable implementation, which always maintains snapshots and copies structures on each write, would give your expected guarantee as a matter of routine, but to a mutable implemantation such as `ConcurrentHashMap` this doesn't come naturally.

Comment: For interest you can see how the immutable maps work in Clojure, but beware that their guarantees come at a cost: high GC pressure, lower single-threaded performance, etc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - im talking about a map that will hold ~millions of keys. immutability is not practical here. im still pretty certain what i want is theoretically possible. just cant find any implementations :-)

Comment: Clojure does hold a few surprises for you there---the implementation is not as naïve as you may assume. It is a wide tree implementation, each node having 32 children. It accommodates millions of entries with just 4 levels of depth. Copy-on-write is limited only to the 32-element array affected by an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guaranties you want + very big dataset would involve some transactions mechanism or snapshots locking:

```
Snapshot<K, V> viewport = map.lockSnapshot();
try {
    ... // work with version-fixed viewport.
} finally {
    map.unlockSnapshot(viewport);
}
```

Maybe you need transactional key-value storage? Take a look on GridGain solutions, they have such functionality (and a lot above).

Comment: im (still) trying to avoid full-blown TX stores. so far i've managed to code around this (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64890/threadsafe-hashmap-with-snapshot-support) but im really hoping to hear there's some library/hack that i just didnt find.

Comment: a couple years ago I did not find such library (tried to solve the similar problem). all algorithms lead either to manual snapshots management (as you implement) or to full tx stores.

I have one question: if making a copy of your map will lead to "out of heapspace" - may be you are doing something wrong?

Comment: the input size is huge. its part of the problem domain and not an artifact of my design. what i could do (which im trying to avoid), is bring in a full blown store, like rocksdb or mapdb etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy-on-write map implementation:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

/**
 * A thread-safe version of {@link Map} in which all operations that change the
 * Map are implemented by making a new copy of the underlying Map.
 * <p/>
 * While the creation of a new Map can be expensive, this class is designed for
 * cases in which the primary function is to read data from the Map, not to
 * modify the Map.  Therefore the operations that do not cause a change to this
 * class happen quickly and concurrently.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:Kuzma.Deretuke@gmail.com">Kuzma Deretuke</a>
 */
public class CopyOnWriteHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>, Cloneable {
    private AtomicReference<Map<K, V>> internalMap = new AtomicReference<Map<K, V>>();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CopyOnWriteHashMap.
     */
    public CopyOnWriteHashMap() {
        internalMap.set(new HashMap<K, V>());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CopyOnWriteHashMap with the specified initial size.
     *
     * @param initialCapacity The initial size of the Map.
     */
    public CopyOnWriteHashMap(int initialCapacity) {
        internalMap.set(new HashMap<K, V>(initialCapacity));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CopyOnWriteHashMap in which the initial data,
     * being held by this map, is contained in the supplied map.
     *
     * @param data A Map containing the initial contents to be placed into this class.
     */
    public CopyOnWriteHashMap(Map<K, V> data) {
        internalMap.set(new HashMap<K, V>(data));
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Map<K, V> oldMap;
        Map<K, V> newMap;
        V val;
        do {
            oldMap = internalMap.get();
            newMap = new HashMap<K, V>(oldMap);
            val = newMap.put(key, value);
        }
        while (!internalMap.compareAndSet(oldMap, newMap));
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        Map<K, V> oldMap;
        Map<K, V> newMap;
        V val;
        do {
            oldMap = internalMap.get();
            newMap = new HashMap<K, V>(oldMap);
            val = newMap.remove(key);
        }
        while (!internalMap.compareAndSet(oldMap, newMap));
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> newData) {
        Map<K, V> oldMap;
        Map<K, V> newMap;
        do {
            oldMap = internalMap.get();
            newMap = new HashMap<K, V>(oldMap);
            newMap.putAll(newData);
        }
        while (!internalMap.compareAndSet(oldMap, newMap));
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        internalMap.set(new HashMap<K, V>());
    }

    //
    //  Below are methods that do not modify the internal map
    //          

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return internalMap.get().size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return internalMap.get().isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return internalMap.get().containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return internalMap.get().containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return internalMap.get().get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return internalMap.get().keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return internalMap.get().values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return internalMap.get().entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return internalMap.get().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return internalMap.get().equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Map<K, V> map = internalMap.get();
        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
        if (!i.hasNext())
            return "{}";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('{');
        for (; ; ) {
            Entry<K, V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            sb.append(key == this ? "(this Map)" : (key == map ? "(internal Map)" : key));
            sb.append('=');
            sb.append(value == this ? "(this Map)" : (value == map ? "(internal Map)" : value));
            if (!i.hasNext())
                return sb.append('}').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            CopyOnWriteHashMap<K, V> clone = (CopyOnWriteHashMap<K, V>) super.clone();
            clone.internalMap = new AtomicReference<Map<K, V>>(new HashMap<K, V>(internalMap.get()));
            return clone;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For license information to this file, see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/sandbox/mwebb/mina/src/main/java/org/apache/mina/util/CopyOnWriteMap.java

Comment: This class is similar to mina CopyOnWriteMap, but this is my own non-blocking version.

Comment: my map is expected to be very big (millions of entries). that copy looks like suicide to me